# Handling click and doubleclick on same view in emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I have a component which require to handle both click and double click. Its code is like

**Template :**

```
<div class="routine_week routine-border box-height-fix fl pointer">
{{mark-down marking}}
</div>
```

**Component**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    marking : 0,
    isMarkable : false,

    click : function(){
        //click here
    },

    doubleClick : function(){
        //double click here
    }


});
```

Now issue is that `doubleClick` never got fired. If it does it also fires two `click` events. How can I ensure that `doubleclick` event will not interact with `click`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ember is so powerful** that I was able to imitate DoubleClick using SingleClick event. Its all depend upon **Ember.run** Loop. Here is the code for anyone like me trying to do that -

```
//capture event for singleClick only execute if there is no doubleClick
eventIO : null,

//ember actually execute the doubleClick but it also gives two singleClick
doubleClick : function(){

    var eventIO = this.get('eventIO');

    //check if there is any event for single click, disable it
    if(eventIO != null){
        Ember.run.cancel(eventIO);
        this.set('eventIO',null);
    }

    // do the stuff with double click

},

// our click event which got executed in both single / double click
click : function(){

    var eventIO = this.get('eventIO');

    //if this is the first click , schedule it for later after 500 ms
    if(eventIO === null)
    {
        var eventIO =  Ember.run.later(this,function(){

            //do single click stuff

            var eventIO = this.get('eventIO');

            ///clear additional events
            if(eventIO != null){
                Ember.run.cancel(eventIO);
                this.set('eventIO',null);
            }

        },500);

        //register event to the component
        this.set('eventIO',eventIO);
    }

},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p {{on 'dblclick' this.doubleClick}}></p>
```